# validate field length

Tags: javascript

i want my roll number length should be equl to 4 and the data inserted can only be integer..

how can it be possible through java script

i am trying this code but it is just checking it, if roll number is greater then 4 it displays error but also insert the roll number

```
function rollnumber(elem, min, max){

    var uInput = elem.value;
    if(uInput.length >= min && uInput.length <= max){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert(" nter between " +min+ " and " +max+ " characters");
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }


}
rollnumber(document.getElementById('rollnumber'), 1, 4);

return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It confuses the javascript `rollnumber` is both a function name and an element id.
2. The function needs to be executed on a form when it submits otherwise it will continue submitting instead of stopping
3. Here is the fixed code. Tested.

   ```
   <form onsubmit="e_rollnumber()">
       <input type="text" id="rollnumber" />
       <input type="submit" value="Click here to roll the number" />
   </form>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       function e_rollnumber(){
           var len = {min:1,max:4};
           var input = document.getElementById('rollnumber');

           if(input.value.length>=len.min && input.value.length<=len.max) return true;
           alert("Please enter between " +len.min+ " and " +len.max+ " characters");
           input.focus();
           return false;
       };
   </script>
   ```